# Como iterar los indices de un array dinámico en NodeJS y JSON

Tags: javascript, json, array, nodejs

tengo un array dinámico que se va creando por medio de una API..

EL `array` llamado `events` tiene la siguiente estructura:

```js
0:{
"id": 
"idFixture": 1
"idSeason": 1
"idTeam": 1
"teamName":"xx"
"idPlayer1":1
"player1Name":"xx"
"idPlayer2":1
"player2Name":1
"elapsed":1
"elapsedPlus":1
"type":"xx"
}
```

Donde el cero es el indice del array que se va incrementando conforme a los que eventos vayan sucediendo...

Ejemplo..

un arreglo de eventos puede estar conformados así:

```js
"events":[
0:{...}
1:{...}
2:{...}
3:{...}
4:{...}
etc..
]
```

Necesito crear una instrucción donde itere cada indice dinámico del evento que vaya saliendo para así podes condicionar variables como el id, el playerName etc.

Tengo claro que esta linea de código `res.body.results.map(e => e.events[0])` me ubica el el evento de indice 0 y funciona perfecto para mí, pero al momento de condicionarlo con

```js
   if( (res.body.results.map(e => e.events.type) == 'goal') {
          // xx
  }
```

No sentencia nada, quiero decir que posiblemente ocupe un ciclo for iterando con length y el indice [0], es toda la idea que tengo en mente pero no se llevarla a cabo, si alguien me puede ayudar estaría genial :)

Answer (score 1):

Apenas caigo en cuenta que lo que hiciste esta bien excepto por un pequeño detalle...

mira lo siguiente:

```
if((res.body.results.map(e => e.events.type) == 'goal') {
    // xx
}
```

según tu respuesta estas comparando si el array entero es igual a 'goal'.

Lo que tendrias que hacer es:

```
res.body.results.map(e =>{ 
    if(e.events.type == 'goal'){

        //Acciones a realizar por cada coincidencia...
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Ahí ya estarias comparando es que cada elemento del array que tenga la propiedad events y dentro de esta la propiedad type, que dentro del atributo type el valor sea igual a 'goal'.

Otra cosa es que el if iba dentro del map...